# How do i backup of Azure SQL database from one to another?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I have two Azure SQL database as Prod & Testing. Both are available in different region. I would like to copy of one database from Prod to Testing every night. Is this possible to do using Azure Automation?

Answer (score 1):

For your Question, "Is this possible to do using Azure Automation", yes it is.

Now there can be multiple methods by which you can achieve this.

**BACPAC route** : Answer by @Venkataraman R is absolutely correct but you should keep in mind that.

1. If you DB size is big (somewhere like 150+ GB) and you have lots
   of indexes in your big tables, then this method could take around
   1.5 to 2 hours.
2. Also, you need to have a blank DB created before hand. BACPAC
   restore command do create Db for you if it is not already there but
   then its maximum size is caped at 32 GB. If you DB is bigger then
   you need to create it before hand.
3. One big pro for this method is you can copy your DB even on on-prim
   machines.

**Using PowerShell New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy cmdlet in Azure Automation:**

Explained [here](https://blog.novanet.no/how-to-create-a-database-copy-using-azure-automation/). for bigger DB's this method takes very less time compared to BACPAC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps.[Reference link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfb2b69e-cb20-4518-8764-c27ca04c0835/automated-restore-of-azure-sql-database-to-on-prem)

1. Take BACPAC of the PROD database and put in the Azure storage blob.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /a:Export /ssn:"azure_db_server" /sdn:"azure_db_name" /su:"user_name" /sp:"password" /tf:"file.bacpac"
```

2. Restore the BACPAC from step 1 to the testing environment.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /a:Import /SourceFile:"file.bacpac" /TargetServerName:".\SQLEXPRESS"  /TargetDatabaseName:CopyOfAzureDb
```

You can do these using azure automation.

There is also a [quick reference for Azure automation steps for exporting bacpac to Azure blob storage](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/azure-automation-automated-export)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm also looking automation to do this activity. But this azure automation templates simply taking backup to Blob storage. But i should take backup from Prod to Testing Azure SQL Database Server.

Comment: @LakshminarayananS, you need to put the PROD bacpac in the Azure storage blob as intermediate step and then import from there to your testing environment. You just need to create runbook with these steps.